# In what test cases could this fail to give the right output and what are potential solutions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testcase

I need to take a list of integers and multiply its elements such that I get the greatest number possible. This number, I need to output as a string.
Example:

```
(int list) givenList = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0]
Output: 8  
//because (2)*(2)*(2)=8

(int list) givenList= [-2, -3, 4, -5]
Output:60  
//because (-3)*(-5)*(4)=60
```

Here is my code:

```
import operator
xs = [0,0]
if  xs.count(0) == len(xs) :
    print ("0")
elif xs.count(0) == len(xs)-1:
    print ("0")
else:
    negatives =[]
    legits = []
    listLength=len(xs)
    counter = 0
    while counter < listLength:
        if xs[counter] <0:
            negatives.append(xs[counter])
        if xs[counter] > 0:
            legits.append(xs[counter])
        counter = counter +1

    if len(negatives)%2 !=0:
        negatives[negatives.index(max([n for n in negatives if n<0]))] = 1

    newList = negatives + legits
    print str((reduce(operator.mul, newList)))
```

Comment: Doesn't your current code cause `[0,5]` to be reported as `0` instead of `5`?

Comment: The list `[-1]` will be reported as `1` instead of `-1`.

Comment: @BillLynch oh MY! You are absolutely right, I cannot believe I completely overlooked that :(

Comment: @BillLynch I explicitly tested [-1]; it is reported as 0

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense to me given the code. You'll put `-1` in negatives, and then because there's an odd number of negatives, you'll change it to `1`. Then newList will consist of `[1]`, and so the reduction should produce `1`. But if you're happy with that output then sure.

Comment: I just started working with python this afternoon, and most of my help came from previous answers n this site. With the little I knew, that was the best I could do to get the right answer while not breaking something else in the process. I'm never satisfied with my code, and would be very very happy if you could show me how to @BillLynch

Comment: You can merge your `if` and `elif` conditionals into `if xs.count(0) == len(xs) or xs.count(0) == len(xs) - 1:`,

Comment: We can also use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: Last suggestion: How about try something like `return str(reduce(operator.mul, filter(lambda x: x != 0, xs)))`? Another option (to take into account the possibility of an empty list) is to separate `filter()` to create a new list and check if the list is empty. If it is empty, proceed with reducing the list. Otherwise, skip and print `"0"`.

Comment: Great suggestions. Thank you